# Error creating migrations with Pomelo EF net-core 3.0, database: MySql

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core-3.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am creating a web service with connection to MySql using EF and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql. The project is compiled normally, but when using the "Add-Migration newVersion" command the error occurs:

"Method 'get_Info' in type Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure.Internal.MySqlOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Pomelo.
EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Version = 2.2.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null 'does not have an implementation. "

I'm not sure what the reason (version mismatch or incorrect settings), I'm new to net-core , thanks if you can offer help. The code is in Github:

https://github.com/vcalazas/project19092019

[bugs picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiHz7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be creating a dotnet core v3 project, but the Pomelo driver appears to target v2.2.   Try 'downgrading' your project to 2.2.

Comment: There is a release candidate for .NET Core 3.0 now. https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/797#issuecomment-538791188

Comment: The 3.0 release candidate still seems to have problems. Its not working for me. I try to use my code first reverse engineer code (using scaffolding) on it and get errors

Comment: @Menace If you still get errors. please open an issue on our GitHub repo.

Comment: The 3.0 full release is good. Though I found the bool type scaffolding to be a problem. There is a work around.

Comment: While Neils general statement goes in the right direction, it is actually not the .NET Core version but the EF Core version that is the problem here. There should be no issue in using .NET Core 3.0 with EF Core 2.2.6 and Pomelo 2.2.6. Of course now (2,5 months later), you could just use the released Pomelo 3.0.1 or even the prereleased Pomelo 3.1.0-rc1 (in conjunction with the appropriate EF Core version) for that matter.